# What are the prerequisites to learning Axios?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm trying to learn axios, because the previous developer on my work is using axios, I'm pretty new to web development, especially back end. I focus more on frontend ( using vue js mostly ) so I'm asking if there is something that I should learn first before learning axios? I'm not familiar in get, post or promise etc. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing enough about basic Javascript, ajax fundamentals, array.map, promises and callback functions will be sufficient.

Ref: https://flaviocopes.com/axios/[https://flaviocopes.com/axios/][1]

Comment: Thanks a lot, one question. should i learn AJAX too?

Comment: yes, absolutely